# Windows Photo program does not recognise media in Windows Pictures directory symbolic hard link

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, photos, windows-photo-viewer

Windows Photo program does not recognise media in Windows Pictures directory after the directory has symbolic hard link to another folder. How can that be fixed?

I had symbolically linked (/J) the Windows Pictures directory to another folder on an external hard drive. Now the Windows Photos program does not recognise the media inside, even after leaving it overnight.

Comment: It's not clear what you did. There are no directory hard links. The /J switch creates a directory junction, not a symbolic link. And what exactly is the Windows Pictures directory?

Comment: thank you for the comment. I ran this command: mklink /J "C:\Users\Desktop\Pictures" "D:\Other Folder\". I believe the Pictures folder at the side of File Explorer points to that folder (C:\Users\Desktop\Pictures) by default. Hope that clarifies